# INSERT data from one form into a chosen MySQL table via buttons

Tags: php

I have an HTML form with two buttons (one adds to a main archive table and one adds to a drafts table to be edited and submitted later). I cannot figure out how to make this work with the two buttons (a button becoming the insertion into a table)

The code is now very messy and filled with other ideas/techniques but any good coder will see I have no idea what I'm at.

Here's the two buttons from the `<form>`:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submit" value="archive">Add to Archive</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name="submit" value="drafts">Save to Drafts</button>
```

and here's the PHP file:

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php"); //connection file

//retrieve all the data from the form

$title= ($_POST['title']);
$date= ($_POST['date']);
$series= ($_POST['series']);
$housemates= ($_POST['housemates']);
$houseLocation= ($_POST['houseLocation']);
$length= ($_POST['length']);
$airtime= ($_POST['airtime']);
$type= ($_POST['type']);
$team= ($_POST['team']);
$objective= ($_POST['objective']);
$finalOutcome= ($_POST['finalOutcome']);
$successfulness= ($_POST['successfulness']);

$submit = $_POST['submit']; //following an example from online
$action = $submit;

//send all data to database tables(s)

switch ($action){ //taken from an online example a switch statement - doesn't work
    case 'archive':
    $dbQuery="INSERT into tasks values (NULL,'$title','$date','$series','$housemates','$houseLocation','$length','$airtime','$type','$team','$objective','$finalOutcome','$successfulness')";
    $dbResult=mysql_query($dbQuery);
    break;

    case 'drafts':
    $dbQuery="INSERT into drafts values (NULL,'$title','$date','$series','$housemates','$houseLocation','$length','$airtime','$type','$team','$objective','$finalOutcome','$successfulness')";
    $dbResult=mysql_query($dbQuery);
    break;
}

mysql_close();
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

I do have the form submitting the data to one table (the archive table).

Comment: just as an important security advice: switch to PDO and use prepared statements instead of mysql, or at least mysqli

Comment: Using `mysql_*` functions in new projects totally bad idea. You need to switch `PDO` or `mysqli` and learn something about `Prepared Statements`

Comment: Daniel-Ruf @HddnTHA I've seen quite alot about PDO and mysqli and this is something I am currently learning, I just need to get core functionality out of the way

Comment: @DanielRuf different words same approach. (-:

Comment: @JoshMayes you need to choose right way.

Comment: please show your complete form

Comment: @DanielRuf the complete form isn't very relevant, and I know it works because I have it currently submitting to one table.

Comment: your last } seems to be too much

Comment: @DanielRuf that closes the switch?

Comment: nope, the } before mysql_close() closes the switch-case

Comment: and please don't forget at least mysql_real_escape when using mysql/mysqli. why the ( and ) around your $_POSt-values?

Comment: @DanielRuf yes I've seen that before, and it checks for invalid input? Is that right? I removed that }, thank you!!

Comment: it prevents different hacking attacks/attemps, always sanitize the data which is used in SQL/DB statements

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please do not change the code, let it like it was when you started your question so it fits to the answers

Comment: @DanielRuf sorry, have changed back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, strongly agree with using PDO or mysqli.

As to your question, the value of a `<button>` doesn't get submitted, so you won't see it in `$_POST['submit']`.  You'll need to change it to an `<input>`, something like:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submit" value="Add to Archive">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name="submit" value="Save to Drafts">
```

Comment: I have now changed the buttons to inputs however I have had to change the 'value' surely this will have a knock on affect.

Comment: @JoshMayes in your php switch statement just make sure case matches the value in the input tag.  I.e. switch ($action) case 'Add to Archive': etc.

Comment: Thanks, have done, still no luck in the buttons adding to the relevant tables

Comment: @JoshMayes what's the result of your mysql_query?  Any errors?

Comment: after filling the form out and click one of the buttons, nothing seems to happen, the page redirects to the correct page but nothing gets added to the relevant table

Comment: Instead of using the value of the button, you should use different names. Then, the $_POST array will contain the name of the clicked button.

Comment: the scheme of the database table would help, do you use an autoincrement-field for the index (the first field)?

Comment: if after your query $dbResult = false, then try `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: I took away the redirect and added the var dump and got 'bool(false)'

Comment: so the query fails, what does `echo mysql_error()` say? you can leave the header() there, it will not execute when you output something before it is called or run

Comment: sorry, rookie mistake there. anyway after adding that I get: bool(false) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @JoshM so you have either more or less columns in the table than the number of values in your query.  What's your table structure look like?

Comment: @DavidR That's exacty what it was, I hadn't updated the posts to include the recently added 'notes', and now it works perfectly! Thank you SO much for your help! Now I need to get onto this Mysqli